# Open an Eclipse plugin editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a class which extends the TextEditor for creating an editor view. I have done all the required entries, like in `plugin.xml`. Now I am getting the following error in opening the editor...

> org.eclipse.core.runtime.AssertionFailedException: null argument:The editor input must have a non-null name

I am using the following code for opening the editor.

```
IWorkbenchPage page =
    PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
page.openEditor(input, xyz.ID);
```

Comment: You should inspect your `input` object, as error message suggest. Are you using `FileEditorInput` or something else? Does your input containg any real data?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The following code is the correct solution for the problem.

```
if (fileToOpen.exists() && fileToOpen.isFile()) {
    Stirng path = // file path that to be input.;
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    URI fromString = org.eclipse.core.runtime.URIUtil.fromString("file://" + path);
    try {
        IEditorPart openEditor = IDE.openEditor(page, fromString, XYZEditor.ID, true);
        IEditorInput editorInput = openEditor.getEditorInput();
        //editorInput.
    } catch ( PartInitException e ) {
        //Put your exception handler here if you wish to
    }
}
```